# YUV color space and chrominance

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, pixel, yuv

Ok. To be short suppose:

1. I have a monochrome image; And initially it represented in RGB color space.
2. I don't know in what sequence I shall do this, but I need to convert image to YUV space (a) and load it into `PictureBox` control (b) and make few color scribbles;
3. And finally I need to learn/know somehow what pixels were colored.

   And how do I draw lines/dots on loaded image in `PictureBox`?

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a monochrome image from RGB to YUV is very simple:

```
Y = R
U = 0
V = 0
```

Y is the luminance, calculated as `0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B`, but as R = G = B for a monochome image, it's the same as `(0.299+0.587+0.114) * R` which is simply `1 * R`.

U is calculated as `0.436 * ((B - Y) / 0.886)`, but as Y = B it is always zero.

V is calculated as `0.615 * ((R - Y) / 0.701)`, but as Y = R it is alwaus zero.

---

To draw lines on a `Bitmap` object, you use the `Graphics.FromImage` method to create a `Graphics` object for it, then use the `DrawLine` method to draw lines.

To draw pixels, use the `SetPixel` method of the `Bitmap` object.

Comment: +1 Good answer, but with one caveat... the color matrix you're talking about above is for old NTSC/EBU conversion and can cause shrifting if mixing & matching in a chain.  I think you've given the op plenty to start with, but for posterity's sake, I'm calling it out as "don't just copy this".

Comment: I need to modify image after I draw lines. How do I do that. And about conversion. How do I programatically determine wheter image I upload is monochrome? If R == G && G == B && B == R?

Comment: @John Green: If I understand you right, you are referring to that YUV is used for analog encoding, and it's entirely possible that it's actually the YCbCr color space that is desired, which has a different conversion.

Comment: @Guffa - Yes, though the differences are minor.  Properly, YUV refers to the old EBU format, and YIQ refers to the old NTSC format.  YCbCr still converts with the coefficients you have above, but it will not produce the image exactly as it would if put through, say, a modern compression scheme's converter.

Comment: @helicera: You can modify the image any way you like after drawing the lines. To check if a color is monochrome you only need to check `R == G && G == B`, if that is true, you know that `B == R` is true also.

Comment: I understand it's a transitive rule, oops) Thank you!